# Variable changing value in loop "IF" without correctly condition

Tags: c, if-statement

I want know why me variable test change to 1, considering that I don't have a sequence like:
0 or 255 > 0 or 255 > 0 or 255 > 0 or 255

Why my if condition doesn't working?

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int item[4]={1,2,3,4};
  int test =0;

  printf("test: %d\n", test);
int i =0;
            if( (item[i] == 0 || 255) && (item[i+1] == 0 || 255) && (item[i+2] == 0 || 255)  &&
             (item[i+3] == 0 || 255) && (item[i+4]== 0 || 255))
              {
                test =1;
              }
                   

  printf("test after if:%d\n\n\n",test);
}
```

result:

`test: 0  test after if:1`

I want result `test` after if `= 0` because my condition is: sequence 0 or 255 4 times

Comment: The condition `item[i] == 0 || 255` is the same as `(item[i] == 0) || 255` which is *always* true. You want `item[i] == 0 || item[i] == 255`

Comment: considering `(item[i] == 0) || 255`, my another values i+1...i+2...i+n, don't is true value 0 or 255, why my condition `&&`doesn't working? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: On a different note, if you know you're always doing to check four elements at a time, then you can do the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)` and skip the `if (i + 4 < 10)` check.

Comment: considering vector `int item[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`i dont have 0 or 255 however my test change to 1

Comment: All your sub-conditions are the same, so you have `true && true && true && true` which is, of course, `true`.

Comment: in `int item[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` 0 or 255 not is true but are accepted in if condition

Comment: And if your text-books, tutorials or classes don't teach you about [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), now is the perfect time to learn about it. And probably start looking for some other learning or teaching resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the expression

```
item[i] == 0 || 255
```

is equivalent to

```
(item[i] == 0) || 255
```

That means the condition is true if `item[i] == 0` is true, or if `255` is true. And because `255` is not `0` (`0` is the only integer value that is false) it's true, making your whole condition true.

Since all the sub-conditions in your `if` are the same, you have (basically) `true && true && true && true`. Which is, of course, `true`.

To check if an element is `0` or `255` you need to check the element twice:

```
item[i] == 0 || item[i] == 255
```

Modify all your sub-conditions similarly.